# If I enter a link in a textbox, it should behave like a link if we get its output on some page

Tags: php, html

I want to create a textbox like if I enter a link in it & insert this data into some mysql database by PHP & then I get its output on a php page, it should behave like that specific link.

Eg:

```
<form>
<input type="" name="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

suppose I enter http://stackoverflow.com in the textbox & get output of this text then the output should be exactly http://stackoverflow.com, which when clicked should take me to http://stackoverflow.com...

this textarea of stackoverflow.com in which I'm adding this question is also just like what I want...

Please tell me if someone knows.

Thanks!!!
Muddser

Answer (score 1):

Just parse your outputted text with [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), which is what StackOverflow uses a flavour I believe.

```
<?php

require 'libs/markdown.php';

// do your database connection

$sql = "SELECT text FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1";
$res = $db->query($sql);
$row = $res->fetch($res);

echo Markdown($row['text']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['text']){
    preg_match_all('~((https?|ftp)://.*?) ~', $_POST['text'], $urls);
    foreach($urls[1] as $url){
        echo file_get_contents($url); // you can change echo to whatever you want

    }
}
```

and change method to POST

Comment: Thanks for this, But this is not what I want. I insert data through a page into mysql table... and then I use select from php command to get the output of that table... then how would I get the output? and also I may enter both links & plain text at a time... then I want link to behave as link & plain text to behave as plain text... Thanks!!!

Comment: Sir can you please give me an example of this... I need it really badly... please help me...

Answer (score 0):

It would better to take off HTML tags first:

```
strip_tags($field);
```

and then replace links to HTML format. You can use example [this function](http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/convert-links-into-clickable-hyperlinks)